# How is a SQL table different from an array of structs? (In terms of usage, not implementation)

Tags: sql, data-structures, struct, ddl

Here's a simple example of an SQL table:

```
CREATE TABLE persons
(
    id INTEGER,
    name VARCHAR(255),
    height DOUBLE
);
```

Since I haven't used SQL very much, I haven't yet learned to think in its terms. Effectively, my brain translates the above into this:

```
struct Person
{
    int id;
    string name;
    double height;

    Person(int id_, const char* name_, double height_)
    :id(id_),name(name_),height(height_)
    {}
};
Person persons[64];
```

Then, inserting some elements, in SQL:

```
INSERT INTO persons (id, name, height) VALUES (1234, 'Frank', 5.125);
INSERT INTO persons (id, name, height) VALUES (5678, 'Jesse', 6.333);
```

...and how I'm thinking of it:

```
persons[0] = Person(1234, "Frank", 5.125);
persons[1] = Person(5678, "Jesse", 6.333);
```

I've read that SQL can be thought of as two major parts: data manipulation and data definition. I'm more concerned about organizing my data in the first place, as opposed to querying and modifying it. There, the distinctions of SQL are immediately obvious. To me, it seems like the subtleties of how data can and should be structured in SQL is a more obscure topic. Where does the array-of-structs analogy I'm automatically drawing for myself break down?

To give a concrete example, let's say that I want each entry in my `persons` table (or each of my `Person` objects) to contain a field denoting the names of that person's children (actual fruit-of-your-loins children, not hierarchical data structure children). In reality, these would probably be cross-table references (or pointers to objects), but let's keep things simple and make this field contain zero or more names. In my C++ example, I'd modify the declaration like so:

```
vector<string> namesOfChildren;
```

...and do something like this:

```
persons[0].namesOfChildren.push_back("John");
persons[0].namesOfChildren.push_back("Jane");
```

But, from what I can tell, the typical usage of SQL doesn't mirror this approach. If I'm wrong and there's a simple, straightforward solution, great. If not, I'm sure a SQL novice like myself could benefit greatly from a little cogitation on the subject of how databases of SQL tables are meant to be used in contrast to bare, generic data structures.

Answer (score 2):

> To me, it seems like the subtleties of how data can and should be structured in SQL is a more obscure topic.

It's called "data(base) modeling" and is somewhere between engineering discipline and art (like much of the computer programming). If you are really interested in the topic, take a look at [ERwin Methods Guide](http://tangra.si.umich.edu/~radev/654/resources/ERMGALL.PDF).

> Where does the array-of-structs analogy I'm automatically drawing for myself break down?

At persistency, concurrency, consistency and scalability.

- **Persistency**: The table is automatically saved to the permanent storage. It'll stay there and survive reboots (not that a real database server will reboot much) until you explicitly delete it or there is a catastrophic hardware failure. DBMSes have well-oiled backup procedures that should help in the latter case.
- **Concurrency**: Tables are meant to be accessed and (need be) modified by many clients concurrently. Mechanisms such as locking and [multi-version concurrency control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiversion_concurrency_control) are employed to ensure clients will not "step on each other's toes".
- **Consistency**: You can define certain *constraints* (such as uniqueness, foreign keys or checks) and the DBMS will make sure they are *never* broken. Furthermore, this can often be done in a *declarative* manner, minimizing chance for errors. On top of that, everything you do in a database is *transactional*, so you reap the benefits of atomicity, consistency, isolation and durability (aka. ["ACID"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID)). In a nutshell, the database will *defend itself* from bad data.
- **Scalability**: A well designed database schema can grow well beyond the confines of the available RAM, and still keep good performance, using techniques such as indexing, partitioning, [clustering](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/clustering/index-organized-clustered-index) etc... Furthermore, SQL is declarative and set-based, which means that the DBMS has the latitude to pick the optimal "query execution plan" for the data at hand, auto-parallelize the query, cache the results in hope they will be reused etc... without changing the meaning of the query.

Answer (score 2):

Your analogy to the array of structs is not bad ... for the beginning.

After this beginning the differences start in relation to organizing data.
Database people love their "Normal Forms" laws. We do not have these laws in C++ or similar programming languages. Organizing data in the tables according to these laws help database engines to do their magic (queries, joins) better, i.e keep databases compact and crunch millions of rows in fractions of a second, and allow multiple requests concurrently. They are not absolute laws: the 1NF (1st Normal Form) is followed in 99.9999% cases, but the bigger the number (2NF, 3NF, ...) the more often DB planners allow themselves to deviate from them.

Description of normal forms can be found for example [here](http://www.anaesthetist.com/mnm/sql/normal.htm).

I will try to illustrate differences on your example.

In your example the fields of your struct correspond to the columns of the database table. Adding vector of the names as a new field of struct would correspond to adding comma separated list of the names into a new column of your table. This is a violation of the 1NF which demands that one cell is for one value - not for the list of values. To normalize your data you will need to have two arrays: one of Person structs, and another new of structs for Child. While in C++ we can use just pointers to link each child to its parent, in SQL we must use the mechanism of the key. You already added id field into Person struct, now we need to add ParentId field to Child struct so that database engine could find the Parent. ParentId column is called foreign key. Another approach to satisfy 1NF instead of creating the new table/struct for children is that we can switch to children-centric thinking and have just one table with a record per child which will include all the information about the parent of the child. Info about the parent obviously will be repeated in as many records as many children this parent has.

Note (this is also considered part of 1NF) that while in the array of structs we always know the order of the elements, in databases it is up to the engine in what order to store the records. It is just mathematical un-ordered set of records, the engine can resort it in internal storage for various optimizations as it likes. When you retrieve the records from the database with the SELECT statement, if you care about the order, you need to provide ORDER BY clause.

2NF is about removing repetitions from your records. Imagine you would have place of work related fields also as part of your Person struct. Imagine it would include Name of the company and company address. If many Persons in your dataset work in the same Company your would repeat address of the company in their records. Probably we wouldn't do these repetitions in C++ either, but nevertheless extracting these repetitions into a separate table would satisfy 2NF. Strictly speaking even if there is no repetitions and all your Persons work in different places, 2NF still requires to extract data about the workplaces into separate table because it requires that one table would represent one entity.

3NF is about removing transitive dependency and is considered kind of optional, so I will not describe it here. See link above.

Another feature of databases quite different from conventional programming of data structures in C++ is the database indexes. Simplifying, index is just a copy of a column (or columns) (i.e vertical slice) into a separate table where they are stored in an inherent for them order and each record in the index retains the reference to the whole record. So, in your example to create index by height you would create another array of 64 elems of the new

```
struct HeightIndexElem
{
    double height;
    Person* pFullRecord;
}
```

and sort them by height in this array. This will allow the DB engine to automatically optimize certain queries. The database engine itself decides when to use certain index. In C++ we usually create maps (Dictionaries in C#) to speed up finding element by certain characteristic but we must use these maps ourselves - no automatic aspect there.

Answer (score 1):

There are major differences:-

- SQL tables are persistent -- (English Tran: written to disk)
- They are transactional -- (really written to disk)
- They can be an arbitary size -- (Tables of a several hundred million rows are quite common)
- They support relational algebra -- (Joins with other tables, filtering etc.)
- Relational Algebra is provable -- For a given SELECT statement there is only one possible correct answer.

The biggest differences are that when you "UPDATE" and "COMMIT" you know your data is saved in the database and will be there until you decide to "DELETE" it. When you update a structure within an array its gone when the machine is switched off.

The other big difference is scale. The size of a modern DBMS is only limited by your hard disk budget.

Answer (score 0):

[I really like farfareast's answer from an academic stand point, but I feel the need to add a more practically oriented answer too.]

SQL tables themselves are "bare, generic data structures" as you call C++'s structures. They are only *different* data structures: a table *is* always an array of (fixed size) structs and the only pointers you can use are foreign keys.

For example, when you are adding a `vector<string>` to your struct, you are already using pointers internally as `string`s are only a "fancy" way of writing `char*`. This would already require a second table in SQL (using a secondayr index column to keep the elements in order). Of course there are things like [postgresql's arrays](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/interactive/arrays.html) that can help in this specific case, but those are "only" shortcuts for similar hand-writeable constructs.

The real difference in data structure and algorithms comes from the fact that you can easily add declarations of index structures. Say you know you need to *always* access `Person`s in the order of their `height`. In C++ you'd use some kind of tree or sorted list to keep them in order. There is an STL container for that. The downside is, that when you need to access them in a different order (say by name), you'll have to add a second tree and duplicate the data or start using pointers to `Person`s. If you add a Person, you need to update all containers and so on. This becomes cumbersome and soon you'll be on the front page of [The Daily WTF](http://thedailywtf.com/). SQL tables on the other side can have attached indices which automatically keep up with new and changed data. Of course, their maintenance also must be paid in performance, but the management of them is basically deciding which are required by your access patterns -- something needed in every case -- and defining them. In contrast to having to rewrite large parts of an application, this is a much more favorable situation.